# 環境依存文字？が表示されてしまう。

Tags: c++

https://atcoder.jp/contests/abc058/tasks/abc058_b

下記コードの部分で，環境依存文字？が表示されてしまいます。
なぜ環境依存文字？が表示されてしまうのでしょうか。
ご教示頂けると幸いです。

```
テスト値
入力：
xyz
abc

正解出力：xaybzc

現在出力値
xaybzc �
```

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string o, e;
    cin >> o >> e;
    
    string ans = "";
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= o.size() + e.size(); i++) {
        ans.push_back(o[index]);
        ans.push_back(e[index]);
        index++;
    }
    
    cout << ans << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[image: 結果]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まあ端的にはループ内で `index` が文字のないところまで進んでしまっているからゴミを拾っているだけっス。 `o[***]` の添え字は `[0 ... o.size())` の半開区間でないといけないの、わかりますよね？今はそうなっていないです。

現コードは `UTF-8` 等のマルチバイト文字を扱おうとすると破綻します。その辺対処が必要ならもっといろいろ考えることが増えます。その辺は設問次第。

Comment: ご指摘，アドバイスを下さりありがとうございます。  
半開区間という言葉の意味を知りませんでした。調べて修正し実施した所，無事ACする事が出来ました。  
とても勉強になりました。  重ね重ねありがとうございます。